# Overlay image on cameraPreview

Tags: android, camera, overlay

**INTRODUCTION**

I have a custom camera app, where I show camera preview over a custom surfaceView. What I need to implement is, create an overlay image from an image resource, that will be shown over the cameraPreview, such as a filter.

I'm been searching about this in different topics but I haven't found something aplicable to my app.

**APPROACH**

I've been trying to set the image as bitamp, using onDraw() method and other options, but I haven't achieved to show the image.

This is my code:

**CODE**

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements PictureCallback {

    private Button btnPhoto;
    CameraPreview cameraPreview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        cameraPreview = (CameraPreview) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        btnPhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTakePhoto);

        btnPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePhoto();
            }
        });
    }

    public void takePhoto() {
        cameraPreview.getCamera().takePicture(null, null, this);
    }
    //...
}
```

_

```
public class CameraPreview extends FrameLayout implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private Camera camera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        createCamera();

        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(surfaceView);

        SurfaceHolder holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        holder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    }

    private void createCamera() {
        //...
            try {
                this.camera = Camera.open(activeCameraId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }
        //...
    }

    public Camera getCamera() {
        return camera;
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        //...
    }
}
```

_

```
<com.uax.cameratakephoto.CameraPreview
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<Button  //THIS IS THE BUTTON TO TAKE THE PHOTO
    android:id="@+id/buttonTakePhoto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

<ImageView  //THIS IS A SMALL PREVIEW OF THE LAST PHOTO TAKEN
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this
Create camera preview  class by extends SurfaceView

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private String TAG = "CameraPreview";

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
        // preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        mCamera.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        StartPreview();
    }

    public void StartPreview() {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your activity
Declare Preview Object and initialize Camera Object as well

```
private CameraPreview preview;
```

After that

```
   // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of ur activity.
    preview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);

    // Create Frame layout
    FrameLayout previewLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

    // Create camera layout params
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams previewlayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.LEFT);

// Add preview to previewLayout
previewLayout.addView(preview, 0);

Bitmap overlayBitmap = getBitmap();
if (overlayBitmap != null) {
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(180);

Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(overlayBitmap, 0, 0, overlayBitmap.getWidth(),
overlayBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

ImageView oImageView = new ImageView(this);
oImageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
previewLayout.addView(oImageView, 1);
}

// Add previewLayout to main layout
linearLayout.addView(previewLayout, previewlayoutParams);
```

That its.

Comment: Looks nice, but I'm still learning this and seems a bit dificult to me to adapt this to my code. It would be nice if you could adapt that to may code, using static calls in xml instead of dinamically,

Comment: what do you mean by static calls in xml ?  what i understand is using your custom CameraPreview class in xml am i right?.

Comment: Well, finally I'm making another aproach to do this. I'm using now Google's sample API CameraPreview. I'll acept your answer to close this post, but i would appreciate if you could have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458468/set-layout-params-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing, but with a TextView over a camera preview. The trick was dettaching it from the XML Layout and attaching it over the Camera´s parent.

The answer is not intuitive at all, but I found how to do it.
Unlike Linear Layouts, order of declaration does NOT define the Z order in Relative Layouts.
I was able of overlaying a textview over the Camera Preview by declaring both views
in XML and, and overlaying them programatically on my Activity's onCreate Method.

Suppose you have an XML with a TextView with a nice transparent backgroud that you want to overlay over the Camera Preview frame layout, because why not?, it looks cool!:

```
<RelativeLayout>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtnombotiga"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ola ke ase"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"    
        android:background="#55ffffff" 
       />
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="240dp">     
  </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If left like that, the camera will cover your text, no matter what :(
To solve it, let´s go programatical, and:
1) detach the TextView from its parent Layout
2) attach it to the camera´s frame layout *after* attaching the camera first.

Heres the code

OnCreate(){
...blaa blaaa...

```
//Create camera instance and reference to our frame Layout
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);        
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
//Add camera to the Frame Layout
preview.addView(mPreview);
//Get reference to the TextView you want to overlay and type something funny
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtnombotiga);     
txt.setText("ola keee aseee!");
//1) Step 1, here comes the magic! dettach the textView from its original Layout
((ViewGroup)txt.getParent()).removeView(txt);
//1) Step 2, voila! attach it to the View, order matters here so it will appear on 
//top of the camera!
preview.addView(txt);
```

This is the general way to do it, If you need more details let me know.
I need to meet deadlines at work, so I use the first solution that comes up to my mind, sometimes not the most elegant or efficient, if you know a better way of doing it, please share it with us!