# Android: Setting a fixed Height for Layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mobile, cardlayout

I'm trying to make the following 'card' layout which shows how an image and everything contained in a layout is set in to a fixed height, which mimics a real life horizontal card.

[image]

What I have made so far:

The following XML is the single grid item I inflate in to a GridView adapter; which is ONE of the above mentioned 'cards'.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/grid_banner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bannerTitle"
            android:layout_width="285dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/grid_image"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/grid_image"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/grid_image"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/grid_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="300sp"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1.0"
            android:shadowDy="1.0"
            android:shadowRadius="5.0"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I understand that I can set a fixed value for the root LinearLayout but would that affect when viewed through different mobile devices? As in, 50dp could look small on a tablet? Am I wrong?

Comment: 50dp is still 50dp on any device, it looks small because the screen is bigger. if you want different sizes for different screen resolutions you need to use those specific `values` folder resolutions and set specific values

Comment: Why not try using layoutWeight? You can do that, and even if you need to set the height of an item explicitly, you can do as @tyczj said and have a values folder to handle the different devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four elements to show for one card

1. Image
2. "V" icon
3. Title (white text)
4. Description (Grey text)

Because title and description overlapping the image at some points so, I would suggest you to use `RelativeLayout` and also set

1. the height of the card at runtime depending on the screen width of the device so that it looks similar on all devices.
2. Use Values folder for different type of devices and set the size in dp from there.

Comment: Do you have any example code that I refer to when setting the size values please? :) and by setting the height at runtime, you mean the onCreate?

Comment: This would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458468/set-layout-params-dynamically